# Run formula calculation in Google Sheets without to open file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a scheduled addon, which writes data periodically into a Google Sheet, without to open file. I have a formula, which should make some calculations on written data and write calculated values into the sheet, so then Data Studio with this sheet as data source updates the visualization.

What is the way to periodically run a formula calculation and write calculated values without manual steps like opening file?

I'm pretty new to this topic: my search approaches to find something like *convert formula to app script* or *schedule formula execution* brought me not to any fruitful idea.

PS_ the formula, which should do the calculation is:

```
=IFERROR(((VLOOKUP(A2,'[1]SV'!$A:$B,2.0))/B2)+(IF(B2=1,"33,9",IF(B2=2,"16,28",IF(B2=3,"10,36",IF(B2=4,"7",IF(B2=5,"5,64")))))+IF(B2=6,"4,13",IF(B2=7,"3,27",IF(B2=8,"2,61",IF(B2=9,"2,18",IF(B2=10,"1,82")))))+IF(B2=11,"1,77",IF(B2=12,"1,81",IF(B2=13,"1,85",IF(B2=14,"1,9",IF(B2=15,"2,04")))))+IF(B2=16,"1,68",IF(B2=17,"1,61",IF(B2=18,"1,65",IF(B2=19,"1,62",IF(B2=20,"1,59","0")))))),0)
```

If i would know, how to convert the formula to app script, i would manage the rest - i'm familiar with running scripts with time based trigger. Or, maybe, there is a method to run formula on the same scheduled way, like scripts...?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I also have a question for you, so far how have you been deploying your project?

Comment: @Baby_Boy currently it is deployed as a Google Sheet with a scheduled addon. With this addon i write into the sheet some JSON data from a remote API. The next steps are:to make a calculation and to connect the sheet to Datastudio for visualization.

Comment: Regarding convert the formula to Apps Script you should post a new question and include on it the respective description of your search/research efforts. Related [Implementing vlookup and match in function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56843885/1595451)

Comment: What about dummy placement of `NOW()` function in the formula (like `IF(ISDATE(NOW()), <code>, "")`), that is recalculated on time trigger and so forces the formula to be recalculated too?

Comment: @astentx interesting approach, indeed! I'll definitely take it into consideration. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

### *Disclaimer: I have not tried this and it might not work, if it doesn't, comment and I will try to provide another solution

OK here's what i would try:
In google scripts there is a trigger function, manly used for testing. what it does is it runs your script and sends you an email if there is a error, and hypothetically, you could use this to run you script periodically.

---

A couple of other things I may try if this doesn't work, leave a comment if you would like me to go in depth about these:

---

depending on how you want this to work, you could set up a web app to do this, and instead of opining google sheets open the web app with a timer built into the script, that would trigger as long as you had the web page opened.

It might also be possible to run the script automatically with a JavaScript function, requires more research.

Comment: This is what i guess could be the way: to convert the formula to the script, and then execute this script with time based trigger. But i can't find nowhere the way to make a script from a formula.

Comment: @Evgeniy Add the formula to the question.

Comment: so... what is this, an excel formula or something else?

Comment: @Baby_Boy, yes, it was an Excel formula. Then i decided to automat the whole procedure, so i try to convert all to Google Sheets and Data Studio. So the formula too - it is converted to Google Sheets syntax.

Comment: can you give me the original excel formula, before google sheets syntax?

Comment: My Excel is in German language. German original looks like `=WENNFEHLER(((SVERWEIS(A2;'[SV.xlsx]Brand+Non-Brand Keywords mit SV'!$A:$B;2;0))/B2)+(WENN(B2=1;"33,9";WENN(B2=2;"16,28";WENN(B2=3;"10,36";WENN(B2=4;"7";WENN(B2=5;"5,64")))))+WENN(B2=6;"4,13";WENN(B2=7;"3,27";WENN(B2=8;"2,61";WENN(B2=9;"2,18";WENN(B2=10;"1,82")))))+WENN(B2=11;"1,77";WENN(B2=12;"1,81";WENN(B2=13;"1,85";WENN(B2=14;"1,9";WENN(B2=15;"2,04")))))+WENN(B2=16;"1,68";WENN(B2=17;"1,61";WENN(B2=18;"1,65";WENN(B2=19;"1,62";WENN(B2=20;"1,59";"0"))))));0)`

Answer (score 1):

If Google Data Studio is not showing you the correct value then you could use a time-driven trigger to save the formula results in another cell. Example:

```
function respondToTimeDrivenTrigger(e){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  /** The range holding the formula */
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange('Sheet1!A1');

  /** The value returned by the formula */
  var value = range.getValue();

  /** Write the value to the cell to the right or the source cell */
  range.offset(0,1).setValue(value);
}
```

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: The thing is: i want to make calculation without to open the file. The formula works - but to run it i must open the file. So i'm searching the way to make this calculation automatically, maybe based on any trigger. If i would know, how to convert the formula to app script,  i would manage the rest - i'm familiar with running scripts with time based trigger.

Comment: @Evgeniy I didn't mentioned that you have to open the file. Why do you think that you have to open it?

Comment: Hm, maybe i don't understand how this works, but, suppose, the file is closed, the formula is placed in B2, and the data comes from addon into A2. So, for Datastudio the B2 is empty, until i open the file and formula calculates based on the value from A2, correct?

Comment: @Evgeniy When the add-on adds the data to the spreadsheet it also triggers a recalculation, so B2 should not be empty. Is Google Data Studio getting B2 as an empty cell? By the other side when the trigger is executed it also triggers a recalculation of the spreadsheet made on the server side.

Comment: Wow! Everyday something new! I must test it few times. If so, my problem comes ner to solution. I'll test and report. Thank you!